# Can linux or mac terminal commands scroll up instead of down?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, terminal

I'm wondering if there is a way set a linux or mac terminal so that you are always entering commands at the top of the terminal screen, and previous commands are below it.

Example

```
-----Screen top----
>EnterCommand
>PreviousCommand 1
>final line of Previous Command 1 output 
>second to final line of previous command 1 output
-----Bottom of screen-----
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Such a feature is not built into the [standard *nix terminal driver](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/stty.html); a terminal application would have to be specifically written to translate newlines and line wrapping into upward motion instead of downward. Note that this will likely break a number of [TUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) applications, so it is not recommended to use them with such a terminal application.

Answer (score 1):

This seems pretty close to what you're asking for:

https://github.com/swirepe/alwaysontop

To use it run:

```
git clone https://github.com/swirepe/alwaysontop.git
cd alwaysontop/
source alwaysontop.sh
```

If you decide you like it just source it in your .bashrc or .bash_profile with something like:

```
echo "source ~/alwaysontop/alwaysontop.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, however it didn't work for me.  I posted an issue. We'll see if anything comes out of it.